# can anyone explain me these pandas code, Im looking at a EDA project on a Banking Data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

pd.set_option("precision", 2)

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format

Im not able to figure out what these code line do

Answer (score 1):

These code lines fix float numbers precision to two decimal places for pandas output. I belive it's done because your data is banking data, which contains a lot of different money amounts, which should be displayed with 2 decimal places (because there are 100 cents in a dollar)

Comment: so these lines will roundoff output values up to two decimal places not the data frame values. And can you explain me this '{:.2f}'.format

Comment: Yes, I belive, only output values and not "real" dataframe data (though, you should check). The '{:.2f}'.format is standard Python format representation where "f" goes for float and ":.2" means that there will be only two characters after the dot.